# Write string for 10 seconds

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to think of a way of implementing a self-writing text like those you usually see in 2D games but I found myself in a little bit of a cliff, in other 
words I guess I'm stuck

What would be a nice google search in this particular case?

```
private IEnumerator Narrative(string line, float seconds)
{
    transform.GetChild(narratorPanel).GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 1f; /* Begin narrative */

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            while (seconds >= 0)
            {
                seconds -= Time.smoothDeltaTime;

            // ( seconds / line.Length ) = distance between each character in a timeframe

            // By the end the entire line must be displayed and chances are it's going to disappear immediately after the last character so I'll also have to implement some kind of padding so that the user is able to read it

            yield return null;
            }
        }

    transform.GetChild(narratorPanel).GetComponent<CanvasGroup>().alpha = 0f; /* End narrative */
}
```

Comment: Instead of a fixed time to display the whole text, meaning variable time for each character, why not have a fixed time for each character, meaning a variable time for the whole text depending on character count? The latter would feel more natural (imho) => more text, longer display time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is there a reason why you are implementing your idea that way? Consider the following method and see if it fits what you are trying to achieve.

```
IEnumerator WriteText(string Text,float interval)
{
    string dummyText = "";
    foreach(char s in Text)
    {
        dummyText += s;
        //write to the text object
        _TextObject.text = dummyText;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);

    }
```